# Слетел перевод строк на странице входа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, аутентификация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теперь переведено:

> [image]

Comment: Какая гигантская картинка всё же получается при скриншоте с телефона.